# Best method to do filter using NSPredicate by Coredata or NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, core-data, filter, nsmutablearray, nspredicate

In my app I am using `CoreData` to save data. I have filters in one of my viewController. Like `Sort by NSDate` or `filter by any value`. In this view controller I have `UITableView` which gets populated from `NSMutableArray` and have different filter buttons. In the start, I am fetching all data from `CoreData` table and storing into this `NSMutableArray` and doing `[tableView reloadData]`.

Now to perform filtering I am using `NSPredicate`. So my question is, which method is good to do filtering. Should I pass this predicate to `NSFetchRequest`, fetch all data from CoreData table and again store into array and do reload table or Should I pass this into array and do reload.

Which one is the fastest and consumes low memory.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the situation.

Imagine you are fetching reviews of restaurants in Los Angeles.  If you expect the user to filter for Chinese restaurants and then right after filter for Italian restaurants, it might be faster for you to fetch all the restaurants in Los Angeles (i.e. not use the predicate on the fetch), but use the predicate on the resulting array of objects and pass the result on to the table view.  When the user filters for Italian restaurants, you already have the data available in the results array, so the filtering of it will be quick.  However, storing all the restaurants in Los Angeles might cause the result array to be so big that it wastes memory.  And if the user never refilters the data, you fetched that data for nothing.

If you expect the resulting dataset to be huge, it makes more sense to filter on the fetch (i.e. fetch just the data you need).  But if the user refilters the data for Italian restaurants, you'll have to fetch again, which will take more time.

There is definitely a tradeoff for memory and time.  Which one is more correct depends on the data and the likely usage of the app...

Comment: #Josh, Thanks for your answer. In my case, At the first time I am displaying all data into table, but if user clicks on filter then only I have to perform filtering function.

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me - this is old school pre-iOS8 - still in process of upgrading apps to `UISearchController` from `UISearchDisplayController`.

So keeping that in mind, let's start by defining some properties...

A mutable array variable:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *searchResults;
```

and a couple of string variables:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *stringSearchBarText;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *searchAttribute;
```

The `searchAttribute` property is set as such to enable controller polymorphism in my code, however you could set this as a `Static` or assign a value using a setter.

Then use this (pre-iOS8) `UISearchDisplayController` delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    //  Set search predicate and filter array
    if (searchString && searchString.length) {
        [self setStringSearchBarText:searchString];
        NSPredicate *searchPredicate = nil;
        NSArray *fetchedObjects = nil;
        NSMutableArray *arrayResults = nil;

        [self.searchResults removeAllObjects];

         searchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K contains[cd] %@", self.searchAttribute, searchString];
         fetchedObjects = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects;
         arrayResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[fetchedObjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:searchPredicate]];
        [self setSearchResults:arrayResults];
    }
    //  Return YES to reload the search result table view
     return YES;
}
```

**OR**

To answer your question more simply, don't run another fetch, just place the data you have already fetched into an `NSMutableArray` and filter that data using the convenience method `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:`. Much cheaper and much easier.

---

Also, it may be worth noting that we should not be afraid of large data sets, as there are a number of mechanisms to control the size of the data set you initially fetch.

It has not been better explained to me than in a book from The Pragmatic Bookshelf – "Core Data, 2nd Edition, Data Storage and Management for iOS, OS X, and iCloud" (Jan 2013) by Marcus S. Zarra, and in particular Chapter 4 titled "Performance Tuning”.

IMO top of the list for a solid education in Core Data.

Comment: #andrewbuilder, Thanks. In both case I am using NSPredicate only. But is this filtering method using array is faster than CoreData fetch?

Comment: Every person's implementation is slightly different. If you'd like to know the speed differences relevant to your implementation, I'd recommend you install a couple of thoughtfully placed `NSLog`s to record the time it takes to finalise the data set and load the table view. Do this for each option - `NSFetchRequest` and `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` - and note the differences. I'd suggest that using today's hardware / software combinations, the differences will be minute unless you are dealing with massive data sets. Personally I have found my answer the best solution for my apps.